# Custom dependency require Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, package.json

With the `package.json`, it's possible to do something like this

```
"dependencies": {
    "WindowManager": "./lib/WindowManager"
},
```

But when trying to do this in Electron, it gives me this error:

```
App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot find module 'WindowManager'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (.../desktop/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../desktop/lib/init.js:15:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../desktop/lib/init.js:22:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
```

Is it because of Electron, or am I doing something wrong?

`./lib/WindowManager` is a folder with a `package.json` in it with a `main` pointing to the `WindowManager.js`, so that should work.

Comment: Is the `node_modules/WindowManager` folder being created upon `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

The case you try to do normally works, make sure that the dependency "WindowManager" has been properly copied by the build tools to either:

```
.../desktop/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules
```

or

```
.../desktop/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules
```

If WindowManager  does not exist in the disted node_modules there is something wrong with your build process, hard to be more precise than that.